# How to select objects based on their enum value and then sum another field belonging to the object collection in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, enums, sum

So, I'm using Rails 4, and I have an enum column on my "Sales_Opportunity" object called pipeline_status - this enables me to move it through a sales pipeline (e.g. New Lead, Qualified Lead, Closed deal etc). This all works fine. I'm able to find the number of sales_opportunities that a company has by status through using the following:

```
<%= @company.sales_opportunities.where(pipeline_status: 3).count %>
```

This all works fine. What I want to do is to find all sales_opportunities that have the pipeline_status of "closed_won" (enum value of 4 in my app) and sum the value of each won deal (so I can represent the total value of the customer based on the deals that are won in the system). A Sales_Opportunity in my model has a sale_value field, so I tried:

```
<%= @company.sales_opportunities.where(pipeline_status: 4).each.sale_value.sum %>
```

which returns the following error:

```
undefined method `sale_value' for #<Enumerator:0x007f9b87a9d128>
```

This is probably a trivial error but I can't for the life of me figure out what's going on. Is there where statement returning the enumerator or the sales_opportunity objects with that enumerator? Any help would be gratefully appreciated.

If it helps here are the fields in my sales_opportunities table:

```
  create_table "sales_opportunities", force: true do |t|
t.datetime "close_date"
t.integer  "user_id"
t.datetime "created_at"
t.datetime "updated_at"
t.integer  "pipeline_status",                           default: 0
t.string   "opportunity_name"
t.integer  "company_id"
t.decimal  "sale_value",       precision: 15, scale: 2, default: 0.0
```

end

A Sales_opportunity belongs_to a Company Object and a User Object, if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use aggregate function `sum`

```
<%= @company.sales_opportunities.where(pipeline_status: 4).sum(:sale_value) %>
```

Other possibility is to use

```
<%= @company.sales_opportunities.where(pipeline_status: 4).pluck(:sale_value).reduce(0, :+) %>
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll try that tomorrow morning and up vote if it works.

Comment: Awesome - thanks for the help, I chose the first option and it worked just as requested. Happy New Year!